# Pine Script TradingView Query

Tags: automation, pine-script, percentage

I'm quite new to PINE and I'm hoping for some assistance, or to be pointed in the right direction. My goal is to script BUY/SELL signals which will use a PERCENTAGE of an available sum for use with a trading bot via TradingView.

*For example, starting capital $100, buy signal comes through, which triggers buy of of 25% ($25) worth of X coin.*

I have been unable to find the code to setup the more complicated percentage-based buy/sell orders. Perhaps I'm blind, if so, tell me! :) The below code provided by TradingView would use *all* available capital in the account to make 1 x buy trade... which is not ideal.

```
{
    "action": "BUY",
    "botId": "1234"
}
```

I have tried this to add % but to no avail:

```
{
    "action": "BUY" percent_of_equity 25,
    "botId": "1234"
}
```

Any suggestions? Am I missing anything obvious?

Related Articles:

- [Quadency](https://support.quadency.com/en/articles/4055287-tradingview-bot)
- [TradingView](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above is not related to pine-script, but is part of alarm/webhook action.

If you want to declare equity in your (back)order, inside pine-script, you have to use strategy like something this:

```
strategy(title = "example",
         shorttitle = "myscript",
         overlay = true,
         pyramiding = 1,
         default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity,
         default_qty_value = 50,
         initial_capital = 1000)
```

This get the type as percent of equity, which is 50% declared on qty_value

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll look into it!